# vfork()../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux

I've got a problem when i try to using `vfork()`. Here's the code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
    if(vfork() == 0)
    {
        printf("This is the child process\n");
    } else{
        printf("This is the parent process\n");
    }
}
```

and debug with gdb error infomation:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/shawn/Documents/gcc/demo/./a.out 
This is the child process
This is the parent process
a.out: cxa_atexit.c:99: __new_exitfn: Assertion `l != ((void *)0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a48f77 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Can anybody help?

I am using:

- ubuntu 13.10 64bit OS
- gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8)

Comment: you must know how vfork works and how to use it.Have a glance on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29#Vfork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man page for [vfork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork), says you should never return from the function in the child, or call `exit()` - call either `_exit()` or one of the `exec()` functions.

> vfork() differs from fork(2) in that the calling thread is suspended
>   until the child terminates (either normally, by calling _exit(2), or
>   abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), or it makes a call to
>   execve(2). Until that point, the child shares all memory with its
>   parent, including the stack. The child must not return from the
>   current function or call exit(3), but may call _exit(2).

The error comes after returning from the first `printf` call.

Answer (score 5):

The "no such file" message is because you don't have the source for the C library available. I wouldn't worry about it; you rarely need to look at that.

The crash is because you're misusing `vfork`. The only valid things you can do in the child process are to call `execve` or similar, to replace the process with another program, or call `_exit` (**not** `exit`) to exit. You get undefined behaviour if the child tries to modify any data, return from the function that called `vfork`, or call another function.

If you want the child to be a clone of the parent and able to continue running the same program, use `fork` not `vfork`.